# Issues with Ascii Control Characters in .txt files, XOR encryption, C++

Tags: c++, encryption, text, ascii, xor

C++, I want to be able to "encrypt" and decrypt a .txt file using a character by character XOR with a key of
"1".

I am able to successfully encrypt and decrypt "Hello World" but larger text files seem to have some XORs mapping to Ascii control characters that cause the decryption to not fully decrypt the entire file.

Hello.txt holds "Hello World", output.txt is empty.

How I xor:

```
std::ifstream infile("Hello.txt");
std::ofstream outfile("output.txt");

std::string key = "1";

std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()); //copies file data to contents

infile.close();
int k = 0;
for(std::size_t i = 0; i<contents.length();i++) //character by character
{
  contents[i] = contents[i] ^ key[k]; //"encrypt"
  k = (k+1) % key.length(); //iterate through key (for longer keys)
  outfile <<contents[i]; //write to output.txt
}
outfile.close();
```

The same code is used to decrypt the output.txt but a hardcode change of infile and outfile is needed. Eg. infile("output.txt"), outfile("text.txt");

With a key of "1" if a file contains the character "+", "+" will encrypt to "" (→), and the decryption will truncate everything after the "+", inclusive.

Am I correct in thinking that some values XOR to Ascii control characters that .txt files can not handle (Windows 10)?

Is it possible to correctly "encrypt" and decrypt with my approach of using .txt files to hold the cyphertext?

If possible how do I store Ascii control characters to .txt files?

What should I change to better handle Ascii control characters in the cyphertext?

Comment: Just open encrypted file as binary not text in both cases (second parameter for `std::fstream` ctor)

Comment: I'll look into it and get back, thanks.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `std::ofstream` or `std::istream` object you use 2 parameters ctor, but second parameter has default value (`std::ios::in` and `std::ios::out` respectevely) and that opens the file in the "text" mode by default, which on Windows will enable control character handling and mapping `\r` to "\r\n" and vice versa.

So pass second parameter explicitly:

```
 std::ofstream outfile("output.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

this will open them in "binary" mode and all data will pass through without change.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the files as binary solves the issue.

```
std::ifstream infile("Hello.txt",std::ios::binary); //<---- here
std::ofstream outfile("output.txt",std::ios::binary); //<----- here

std::string key = "1";

std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()); //copies file data to contents

infile.close();
int k = 0;
for(std::size_t i = 0; i<contents.length();i++) //character by character
{
  contents[i] = contents[i] ^ key[k]; //"encrypt"
  k = (k+1) % key.length(); //iterate through key (for longer keys)
  outfile <<contents[i]; //write to output.txt
}
outfile.close();
```